# Build a Rust project on Travis CI with a specific nightly version

Tags: rust, travis-ci, nightly-build

I'm about to build a Rust project but I want to build it with Rust nightly 1.11.0.

At the moment I'm only able to do so:

```
language: rust
rust: 
  - nightly 
  - 1.11.0
```

which builds nightly (latest version 1.13.0 which breaks my build) and the stable 1.11.0 which I cannot use either because I need nightly 1.11.0!

So any way I can set this up? I tried `- nightly 1.11.0` but that seems to be a wrong config.

Comment: The real answer is to update your code to support the newest nightly. If something changed from the nightly, it's not super likely it will change back (unless there was a bug or a good reason the new version is incorrect).

Comment: I'm using a testing framework which did not updated to the newest nightly but still works with 1.11.0. I already issued the problem but meanwhile want to have my tests run through

Comment: Certainly! I just didn't want anyone reading this to think that sticking with an old version of nightly was a good long-term solution.

Comment: He okay I got you - btw. you know a way to do what I wanted to in Travis CI?

Comment: Oh, good point. Looks like Travis is using rustup.sh, not rustup.rs. I've updated the linked duplicate with instructions that should work.